# Changing theorem number systems mid document

Tags: numbering, amsmath, theorems, ntheorem

I have a numbering system setup for most of my document using:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
```

Which produces the obvious:

```
Theorem 1.1
Lemma 1.2
Theorem 1.3
Corollary 1.4
etc.
```

But I'm trying to halfway through the document redefine all the above to look at subsection and not just section:

```
Theorem 2.1.1
Corollary 2.1.2
Theorem 2.1.3
Lemma 2.1.4
Theorem 2.2.1
etc.
```

I can't seem to find a way to do that. Is it possible? I tried using the ntheorem package, but it seems to conflict with:

```
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
```

and my other non-numbered stuff.

Comment: At first guess, it seems a simple `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}` should suffice.

Comment: I tried that, but that makes the final item Theorem 2.2.5 instead of Theorem 2.2.1 But I guess I can reset the counter between each section... just seems a hassle, unless that's the only way?

Comment: ...aaahh, you need to reset `theorem` after every `subsection` (with an `\@addtoreset` or using [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)).

Comment: Perfect! Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it? That's exactly what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}% Update counter printing
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}% Reset theorem counter with every new subsection
\makeatother
```

before starting the new `\subsection` from where you want to have the renumbering occur.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{first}

\begin{lemma}
$1+1=2$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
$2+2=4$.
\end{theorem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}% Update counter printing
\@addtoreset{theorem}{subsection}% Reset theorem counter with every new subsection
\makeatother

\subsection{second}

\begin{theorem}
$3+2=5$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea. I hope you don't want to go back to the first enumeration style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\section{First}

\subsection{first}

\begin{lemma}
$1+1=2$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
$2+2=4$.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{second}
\counterwithin{theorem}{subsection}
\setcounter{theorem}{0}

\begin{theorem}
$3+2=5$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need continuous numbering of the last part, as in your example, probably a new `newtheorem` will be the simplest solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\section{First}

\subsection{first}

\begin{theorem}
2+2=4.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{second}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[subsection]

\begin{theo}
2+2=4.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that would require redefining all of my definitions which rely on my theorem counter. (I only showed 3 for simplicity but I have around 20 and feel like it would be unnecessarily bloaty if it can't be done another way)